# How to disable virtual console tty in host os to access virtual console tty in a virtual os running on it?

Tags: virtualization, tty, debian, console

I have a virtual debian os running over a ubuntu os.I need to access the the virtual console tty of the virtual os by pressing ctl+alt+F1. But whenever I do that the ubuntu os is detecting it and displaying me its console.I tried to maximise the virtual os window and tried the key combination but my virtual os is still not detecting the key press. So is it possible to access the virtual console tty of my virtual os instead of triggering the virtual console tty of my ubuntu system?Any help would be greatfull.

Comment: Your virtualization software probable has a special method for that (passing on special keyboard shortcuts to the VM)

Comment: Actually I don't know which virtualisation software is being used.Here is the link to the virtual os that i am using.

https://www.universal-robots.com/download/?option=26264#section16632

Its based on debian 7 and its used in a robot controller.The ctl+alt+f7 command works in the real robot.So it should also work in the offlline simulator(virtual os) I am using.But only problem is that the ubuntu detects it first than my virtual os